# I need some help on designing a program that will perform a minimization using VBA Excel

Tags: vba, loops, excel

How do I use Excel VBA to find the minimum value of an equation?

For example, if I have the equation y = 2x^2 + 14, and I want to make a loop that will slowly increase/decrease the value of x until it can find the smallest value possible for y, and then let me know what the corresponding value of x is, how would I go about doing that?

Is there a method that would work for much more complicated equations?

Thank you for your help!

Edit: more details

I'm trying to design a program that will find a certain constant needed to graph a nuclear decay. This constant is a part of an equation that gets me a calculated decay. I'm comparing this calculated decay against a measured decay. However, the constant changes very slightly as the decay happens, which means I have to use something called a residual-square to find the best constant to use that will fit the entire decay best to make my calculated decay as accurate as possible.

It works by doing (Measured Decay - Calculated Decay) ^2

You do that for the decay at several times, and add them all up. What I need my program to do is to slowly increase and decrease this constant until I can find a minimum value for the value I get when I add up the residual-squared results for all the times using this decay. The residual-squared that has the smallest value has the value of the constant that I want.

I already drafted a program that does all the calculations and such. I'm just not sure how to find this minimum value. I'm sure if a method works for something like y = x^2 + 1, I can adapt it to work for my needs.

Comment: If there was no limit on your equation, wouldn't that result in an infinite loop?

Comment: Maybe? The thing is, I know the graph of the answers will be in the form of a parabola that opens upwards. Shouldn't there be a way for the loop to see that this value it just calculated is larger than the previous value, so it should step back in the other direction?

Comment: Can you refine your requirements?  What class of equations do you need to support?  y = a*x^2 + b*x + c?  What about other powers like x^3?  Keep in mind that for equations with odd maximum powers of x, the minimum for y is -infinity.  If this is a homework problem please add the homework tag.

Comment: is VBA required? the solver add in will find solution

Comment: I ran out of space here, so I'll update in the actual post! It's for a work project, not school.

Comment: It has to be all automated, so I don't think I can use the solver?

Comment: The minimum of any equation of the form `y = Nx^2 + M` is trivially calculated and does not require iteration to find an empirical answer. Can you elaborate more on what your use case actually looks like?

Comment: you can write a program for numerical differentiation using vba to get the most accurate answer....incrementing x in certain steps wont give you accurate answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the output while looping to look for the smallest output result.

Here's an Example:

```
Sub FormulaLoop()

    Dim x As Double
    Dim y As Double
    Dim yBest As Double

        x = 1
        y = (x ^ 2) + 14
        yBest = y

    For x = 2 To 100
         y = (x ^ 2) + 14
         If y < yBest Then
            yBest = y
         End If
    Next x

    MsgBox "The smallest output of y was: " & yBest

End Sub
```

If you want to loop through all the possibilities of two variables that make up x then I'd recommend looping in this format:

```
Sub FormulaLoop_v2()

    Dim MeasuredDecay  As Double
    Dim CalculatedDecay As Double
    Dim y As Double
    Dim yBest As Double

        MeasuredDecay = 1
        CalculatedDecay = 1
        y = ((MeasuredDecay - CalculatedDecay) ^ 2) + 14
        yBest = y

    For MeasuredDecay = 2 To 100
        For CalculatedDecay = 2 To 100
            y = ((MeasuredDecay - CalculatedDecay) ^ 2) + 14
            If y < yBest Then
               yBest = y
            End If
         Next CalculatedDecay
    Next MeasuredDecay

    MsgBox "The smallest output of y was: " & yBest

End Sub
```