# How to choose a range for a loop based upon the answers of a previous loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sorry the title is so confusingly worded, but it's hard to condense this problem down to a few words.

I'm trying to find the minimum value of a specific equation. At first I'm looping through the equation, which for our purposes here can be something like `y = .245x^3-.67x^2+5x+12`. I want to design a loop where the "steps" through the loop get smaller and smaller.

For example, the first time it loops through, it uses a step of 1. I will get about 30 values. What I need help on is how do I Use the three smallest values I receive from this first loop?

Here's an example of the values I might get from the first loop: (I should note this isn't supposed to be actual code at all. It's just a brief description of what's happening)

```
loop from x = 1 to 8 with step 1

results:

x = 1 -> y = 30
x = 2 -> y = 28
x = 3 -> y = 25
x = 4 -> y = 21
x = 5 -> y = 18
x = 6 -> y = 22
x = 7 -> y = 27
x = 8 -> y = 33
```

I want something that can detect the lowest three values and create a loop. From theses results, the values of x that get the smallest three results for y are `x = 4, 5, and 6`.

So my "guess" at this point would be x = 5. To get a better "guess" I'd like a loop that now does:

```
loop from x = 4 to x = 6 with step .5
```

I could keep this pattern going until I get an absurdly accurate guess for the minimum value of x.

Does anybody know of a way I can do this? I know the values I'm going to get are going to be able to be modeled by a parabola opening up, so this format will definitely work. I was thinking that the values could be put into a column. It wouldn't be hard to make something that returns the smallest value for y in that column, and the corresponding x-value.

If I'm being too vague, just let me know, and I can answer any questions you might have.

Comment: As long as you know your exit criteria, you could put a Do..While loop around a for-next with `Step` equal to something like `(endVal-startVal)/10`  Keep looping until your criteria are met.

Comment: Rather than rolling your own, have you considered using `Solver`?

Comment: I am still puzzled why you don't solve this directly?. While this is slightly different than a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11422004/1248931) you posed, still, the answer can be obtained directly rather approximated through iteration. If it's a matter of "I want to solve this iteratively and not do the math" that's fine, but you might mention that.

Comment: Hmm. On further inspection of your example, [no minimum exists](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+y+%3D+.245x%5E3-.67x%5E2%2B5x%2B12). Suggest changing the question to something solvable, and expand the requirement to include awareness there may be no solution.

Comment: For the example, I just made up some random stuff. In the actual case, it's in the shape of a parabola that opens upwards, so there will be a minimum. I can't use the solver because my program isn't trying to solve something as simple as this. I'm asking this question because whatever method works for a problem like this will work in my program as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nice question.  Here's at least a start for what I think you should do for this:

```
Sub findMin()
    Dim lowest As Integer
    Dim middle As Integer
    Dim highest As Integer
    lowest = 999
    middle = 999
    hightest = 999

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    Do While i < 9
        If (retVal(i) < retVal(lowest)) Then
            highest = middle
            middle = lowest
            lowest = i
        Else
            If (retVal(i) < retVal(middle)) Then
                highest = middle
                middle = i
            Else
                If (retVal(i) < retVal(highest)) Then
                    highest = i
                End If
            End If
        End If
    i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Function retVal(num As Integer) As Double
    retVal = 0.245 * Math.Sqr(num) * num - 0.67 * Math.Sqr(num) + 5 * num + 12
End Function
```

What I've done here is set three Integers as your three Min values: lowest, middle, and highest.  You loop through the values you're plugging into the formula (here, the retVal function) and comparing the return value of retVal (hence the name) to the values of retVal(lowest), retVal(middle), and retVal(highest), replacing them as necessary.  I'm just beginning with VBA so what I've done likely isn't very elegant, but it does at least identify the Integers that result in the lowest values of the function.  You may have to play around with the values of lowest, middle, and highest a bit to make it work.  I know this isn't EXACTLY what you're looking for, but it's something along the lines of what I think you should do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no trivial way to approach this unless the problem domain is narrowed.

The example polynomial given in fact has no minimum, which is readily determined by observing `y'>0` (hence, y is always increasing WRT x).

Given the wide interpretation of

> [an] equation, which for our purposes here can be something like y =
>   .245x^3-.67x^2+5x+12

many conditions need to be checked, even assuming the domain is limited to polynomials.

The polynomial order is significant, and the order determines what conditions are necessary to check for how many solutions are possible, or whether any solution is possible at all.

Without taking this complexity into account, an iterative approach could yield an incorrect solution due to underflow error, or an unfortunate choice of iteration steps or bounds.

I'm not trying to be hard here, I think your idea is neat. In practice it is more complicated than you think.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've been much more clear, and shouldn't have chosen that particular equation. This program will only ever have to deal with a parabola opening upwards. It definitely would not work an equation of any other degree.

Comment: Fair enough. Now that we know this about the problem space, is there a reason you want an iterative approach instead of solving for the minimum directly and exactly (it's a pretty trivial calculation)?

Comment: Yes there is. It's somewhat hard to explain, but I tried to explain it at the end of this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422004/i-need-some-help-on-designing-a-program-that-will-perform-a-minimization-using-v